# How to force the layout of glyphs positioned far outside the UITextView's vertical bounds?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, cgrect

No code is needed here.  I need some guidance on how to layout all of the glyphs of a very long multi-line string to be shown in a UITextView with scrolling enabled.  Some background information to understand the circumstances.

Background:  I have a very long multi-string text that needs to be presented in a UITextView with scrolling enabled.  I created a function that identifies the `CGRect` position of a search string match in a multi-line string and then animates the user to the `CGRect` position of the match.  This is accomplished by passing the `CGRect` of the matched text to `contentOffset` which animates the scroll to the location.  The `CGRect` passed to `contentOffset` is generated using `layoutmanager` to ensure accuracy.  In other words, the `CGRect` of the text is based on the position of the matched string's glyph.

However, if the `CGRect` of the matched search string is vertically positioned far away from the UITextView `bounds.height` the animation actually fails.  There is no scrolling whatsoever.  It is as if the scroll animation does not know where to find the `CGRect` position to scroll to the matched string.  I can correct the problem if I first manually scroll to the very bottom of the UITextView and then execute the animation to the `CGRect` position of the matched search string. Under such circumstances, it is as if the UITextView has a complete picture of the text layout and can accurately find the location of the matched search string's `CGRect` in the multi-line string.

Based on the foregoing, it is apparent to me that the UITextView does not layout all of the glyphs of the multi-line string at once.  The view likely draws the glyphs in chunks similar to the way a table view creates cells. It also appears to me that the UITextView has the ability to retain all of the glyph layout information as I manually scroll past the view's bounds to the very bottom of the content vertical size.

Is there any code available that effectively lays out the entire content size of the UITextView even if the glyphs are far outside of the UITextView's vertical bounds?  It appears I need to first layout all of the glyphs to prevent the error above.

Comment: What's wrong with `UITextView`'s `scrollRangeToVisible` method?

Comment: Rob - Yes, scrollRangeToVisible  knows where to find the match.  However, the function has an inherent animation that conflicts with the animation I run.   I can disable scrollRangeToVisible's inherent animation. There is a problem:  my animation sequence also uses a subview, a rectangle with a boarder the size of the matched text.  The subview animates with the scroll and circles the matched text to serve as a visual cue.  The subview uses the CGRect of the glyph.  The subview gets lost too.   scrollRangeToVisible does not provide a solution to locating the subview to the correct location.

Comment: Have you checked that the text view's `contentSize` is large enough to contain your `CGRect` before trying to scroll? Perhaps the `contentSize` isn't being updated properly if you're triggering additional incremental layout outside of the text view's control.

Comment: Not directly.  I do check to see if the rect of the last match (I increment through an array of matches) is located within the bounds of the textview.  If false, then the user has the ability to increment through the array of matches by pressing a button that initiates the animation sequence described above.  In short, the animation is not available unless the match is located outside the bounds of the textview.  The error occurs when the matched text is at very large distance from the bounds of the textview.

Comment: Rob- As I think about your suggestion, anytime I have accessed `contenSize`, I get the complete size before the animation is triggered.  There has to be some object that can be updated to provide the needed layout info.  How does scrollRangeToVisible accomplish the task?

Comment: @KDiaz - you state you are *"using layoutmanager to ensure accuracy"* ... are you using the `.ensureLayout(..)` and / or `ensureGlyphs(...)` functions?

Comment: DonMag ..  I am using  `let matchTxtRect = textView.layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: matchRange, in: textView.textContainer)`  where `textView` is the UITextView object and `matchRange` is an NSRange value but only one element of an array of matched ranges found in the multi-line string.

Comment: @KDiaz - immediately before you call `let matchTxtRect = textView.layoutManager.boundingRect(...)`, try calling `textView.layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: textView.textContainer)` --- if that doesn't help, look at the other *ensure* functions available: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1402967-ensurelayout

Comment: DonMag - That did the trick.  Thank you.   I placed `.ensureLayout` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which works perfectly.   Slowly but surely, I am coming to better understand the UIKit objects.  -Keith

Comment: @KDiaz - Glad that worked for you. I added an answer with a bit more explanation for anyone else who may come across this issue in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons, the entire content layout of a `UITextView` is not necessarily determined when you might expect it to be.

For example, if you have enough text in a text view to span 10-times the visible area, `UIKit` may "hold off" on laying out the text. After all, just because the text is there doesn't mean the user will ever scroll to it.

`NSLayoutManager` provides several functions which allow you to ensure the full content of your text view has been laid-out when you want to access it (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager):

```
func ensureGlyphs(forCharacterRange: NSRange)
func ensureGlyphs(forGlyphRange: NSRange)
func ensureLayout(forBoundingRect: CGRect, in: NSTextContainer)
func ensureLayout(forCharacterRange: NSRange)
func ensureLayout(forGlyphRange: NSRange)
func ensureLayout(for: NSTextContainer)
```

As per the OP's comments, calling `.ensureLayout` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` solved the issue.

Comment: DonMag...  thx for taking the time to give the matter some thought.  Much appreciated.